# EInvalidGridOperation C++

Tags: c++, c++builder

При событии нажатия на кнопку возникает ошибка EInvalidGridOperation "Fixed row count must be less than row count". Не совсем понимаю суть данной ошибки. 
Когда ошибка выскакивает, то синим выделяется в **Unit1** функция `raschets(matrix)`.

**Unit1**

```
#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop
#include "lab02h.hpp"
#include "Lab01.cpp"
#include "Unit1.h"
#include "FUnit.h"
#include "My_DLL.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm1 *Form1;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
        : TForm(Owner)
{
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
        StringGrid1->RowCount  = StrToInt(Edit1->Text);
        StringGrid1->ColCount  = StrToInt(Edit2->Text);
        memory(StrToInt(Edit1->Text) ,StrToInt(Edit2->Text));
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

void __fastcall TForm1::Button2Click(TObject *Sender)
{
for (int i = 0; i< StrToInt(Edit1->Text); i++)
        for (int j = 0; j< StrToInt(Edit2->Text) ; j++)
                *(*(matrix+i)+j) = StrToFloat(StringGrid1->Cells[j][i]);
raschets(matrix);
FUnit->ShowModal();
}
```

**My_DLL.cpp**

```
#include <vcl.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include "lab02h.hpp"
#include "FUnit.h"
#include "Unit1.h"
#include "My_DLL.h"
#pragma hdrstop

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#pragma argsused
int WINAPI DllEntryPoint(HINSTANCE hinst, unsigned long reason, void* lpReserved)
{
        return 1;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

void raschets(float**F)
{
 FUnit->StringGrid1->RowCount=StrToInt(Form1->Edit1->Text);
 FUnit->StringGrid1->ColCount=StrToInt(Form1->Edit2->Text);
 FUnit->StringGrid2->RowCount=StrToInt(Form1->Edit1->Text);
 FUnit->StringGrid2->ColCount=StrToInt(Form1->Edit2->Text);
 for(int i=0; i<StrToInt(Form1->Edit1->Text); i++)
  for(int j=0; j<StrToInt(Form1->Edit2->Text); j++)
   FUnit->StringGrid1->Cells[i][j]=FloatToStr(*(*(F+j)+i));

        int n = FUnit->StringGrid1->RowCount;
        int m = FUnit->StringGrid1->ColCount;
    // ????????? ?????? ?????? ???????
    float sum = 0;
    float** matrixB = new float*[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        matrixB[i] = new float[m];
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            if (i != j && i != n - j - 1) {
                sum += StrToFloat(FUnit->StringGrid1->Cells[i][j]);
            }
            matrixB[i][j] = StrToFloat(FUnit->StringGrid1->Cells[i][j]);
        }
    }

        FUnit->Edit1->Text = sum;

    // ????????? ????? ???????
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            if (i == j || i == n - j - 1) {
                matrixB[i][j] *= sum;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            FUnit->StringGrid2->Cells[i][j]=FloatToStr(matrixB[i][j]);
        }
    }
        return;
}
```

Comment: Нажмите на другую кнопку. Не все кнопки будут вызывать такую реакцию. Reset точно не такая.

Comment: Другая работает. Дело просто в том, что я сделал программу с репозиторием,и там всё работало, а теперь пытаюсь сделать то же для dll. И вот здесь он ругается.

Comment: @Сятослав предположений может быть много, но вот вероятность угадать Вашу проблему невелика. Так что правьте свой вопрос: что, где и как.

Comment: @Святослав: телепаты сегодня ещё не подтянулись, публикуйте релевантную часть кода, значения переменных и точное сообщение об ошибке. А то у меня вот тоже ошибка -- после нажатия на кнопку программа вылетает, может у вас есть идеи?

Comment: Вот код. Если ещё что-то нужно вывести, пишите.

Comment: Я сразу пас. У меня builder'ов не водится...